# Trouble with Capybara and RSpec on a new model spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capybara

I have searched a lot for a solution, but I could not find it! I am trying to make a rails application after watching Michael Hartl's tutorial and when i fill data manually and submit it nothing happens and nothing records in the Mailers table and I am facing the following error:

```
Failures:

  1) Mailer pages mail us with valid information should send a mail
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit}.to change(Mailer, :count).by(1)
       count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/requests/mailer_pages_spec.rb:31:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.89134 seconds
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/mailer_pages_spec.rb:30 # Mailer pages mail us with valid information should send a mail

Randomized with seed 17352
```

The model file is:

```
class Mailer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company_name, :contact_name, :address, :telephone, :email, :description
  before_save { |mailer| mailer.email = mailer.email.downcase }
  validates :company_name, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :contact_name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 40 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

Controller:

```
class MailersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @mailer = Mailer.new
  end

  def create
    @mailer = Mailer.new(params[:mailer])
    if @mailer.save
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Integration test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Mailer pages" do

 subject { page }


 describe "mail us" do

     let(:submit) { "Send my Mail"}
     before { visit mailers_path }


     describe "with invalid information" do
       it "should not send a mail" do
         expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(Mailer, :count)
         end
     end

     describe "with valid information" do
       before do
         fill_in "Company name", with: "Mailer Company"
         fill_in "Contact name", with: "Mailer Contact"
         fill_in "Address",      with: "Mailer Address"
         fill_in "Telephone",    with: "123-456-789"
         fill_in "Email",        with: "mailer@example.com"
         fill_in "Description",  with: "something to say"
       end

       it "should send a mail" do
         expect { click_button submit}.to change(Mailer, :count).by(1)
       end  
     end
   end
 end
```

And the form:

```
<% provide(:title , 'Mail Us') %>
<h1>Mail Us</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3 hero-unit">

<%= form_for(@mailer) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :company_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :company_name %>

    <%= f.label :contact_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :contact_name %>

    <%= f.label :address %>
    <%= f.text_field :address %>

    <%= f.label :telephone %>
    <%= f.text_field :telephone %>

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>

    <%= f.submit "Send my Mail", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

After **<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>**  added to application layout , I saw that the action is new not create , is that what causing the problem ?? waiting for help

Comment: It works when you fill it in manually and submit?

Comment: No and I don't know what to do

Comment: What error do you get when you try? Add that to your question.

Comment: Updated. thats all i am facing :(

Comment: You should be getting some error, what do you mean nothing happens? Is the same form displayed again?

Comment: I got no error when filling the form manually and also nothing saved to the database, but the error detected by RSpec when testing as I posted above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved :) I didnt add **resources :mailers** in my routes file :D

Answer (score 2):

Your create action specifies that if the object is saved you should be redirected to the root_path, otherwise it should render the form again (render 'new').

Therefore if the form is rendering again then it means validations are failing and your Mailer object hasn't been saved. Add the following to your form to see the errors:

```
<%= form_for(@mailer) do |f| %>
  <% @mailer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <p><%= msg %></p>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it shows nothing :( what should I do ?

Comment: comment out all your validations and before_save in the Mailer model, restart the server and see if it saves properly

Comment: Still the same , even when i set when fails redirect_to about_path , it also did not respond to this action, so now what ?

Comment: How to make it respond to create action ??